# Spotfire Web reports as a slide show?

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I have a dashboard of reports that is built with Spotfire on Prem and published to a web url. The dashboard contains 8 pages.

I want to be able to cast this to a TV mounted in our department and have it continually transition between each page for a few seconds each.

A glorified slideshow of reports. I can currently do this two ways; both manually intensive.

First, by exporting the report as a  Powerpoint and putting it on a timed cycle. This hits two criteria issues: I have to do this manually, and the data is current only to when I created the static report.

Second, opening all pages in their own tab in Chrome and using a Chrome extension like Tab Roulette. This works but I run into a time out issue as the web player has built in inactivity for the reports at 3 hours. To restart I essentially have to restart/login and then open every tab manually and start the extension. The data is also essentially static as the tabs are not refreshed.

Is there a way to do this automatically allowing for when the data is refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

> Sadly, there is no way provided by TIBCO to do this automatically.

We had similar request and upon inquiry,TIBCO Support clearly mentioned they dont have anything inbuilt in the tool to get the rotating dashboard. There reasoning was that since it involves infinite looping they don't want it to be part of the product since infinity means complexity.

Anyways, they suggested us to either use Java Scripting or we can use a good plugin for Chrome called [Revolver-Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revolver-tabs/dlknooajieciikpedpldejhhijacnbda?hl=en) and it serves our purpose.

It has option to refresh the page on loading, that way you will have the current data (provided your dashboard is getting data from the source via any scheduler job in background, check here [Scheduled Updates](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.1/doc/html/tsas_admin_help/GUID-8A271E80-C466-40F4-B206-70EF75CBB94F.html)

I am not sure about the inacitivty timeout though. I wonder if you can set it to the NEVER timeout if possible? Or does the refreshing of the page provided by Tab Revolver will nullify the timeout?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I assumed it was something along those lines. The tab switching chrome extension I used claimed to refresh the tabs but I never saw updated data in my testing. Yours seems to do the trick. I will see if the timeout function triggers in a few hours!